# How can I use bitwise operators on scientific numbers?

Tags: c#

I have the scientific number 10579019E063 that I have received from my temperature sensor (Oregon sensor) that I want to parse.

The python example I'm trying to convert to C#:

```
checksum = 0xE + 0xA + 0x4 + 0xC;
checksum -= (value & 0xF) * 0x10;
checksum -= 0xA;
value >>= 8;
```

value is `10579019E063`, parsing it properly:

```
double value = double.Parse("10579019E063");
```

but now Visual Studio complains that it cannot perform bitwise operations on value because it is not an int.

Someone has a clue? I cant simply cast it, I lose precision?

Comment: a temperature equal to 10^70 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bitwise operations have no meaning for doubles, because their structure is very different from ints.

If you're dealing with numbers larger than 2^31 then you can use long.

If even that is not large enough, you need to switch to BigInteger (in the System.Numerics namespace) It has implementations for the bitwise operations.

10579019E063 is way too big, so you need BigInteger.